# How can I check internet connection with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that need to check if there is internet connectivity before running the rest of the script. For the example using `Test-Connection`

```
if (Test-Connection example.com) {
  Write-Host "Connection available"
  # do-other things
} else {
  Write-Host "No internet connection"
  Exit
}
```

The problem with this approach is if there is no connection it gives this error message:
`Testing connection to computer 'example.com' failed: Cannot resolve the | target name.` and then the actual message follows `No internet connection` but the idea was to have it move to the else clause not giving that error message when there no connection.
For example when there is no internet connection the error message `No internet connection` is printed, that's it, nothing else. How can I achieve this.

Comment: See also: [Determining internet connection using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33283848/1701026)

Comment: You might want to use the common [-ErrorAction parameter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable/): `Test-Connection example.com -erroraction silentlycontinue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test-Connection` doesn't seem to have something that we can catch with try-catch, but there is a `-Quiet` parameter that may do what you want. It translates the output to a simple boolean.

Testing without and with an internet connection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per @mukunda's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70861485/3156906), `Test-Connection` has a `-Quiet` switch that ignores errors and returns a boolean result - see the documentation for [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7.2) for the details.

Note there's some perhaps unexpected behaviour if you're testing multiple sites in a single call:

> If any ping to a given target succeeds, $True is returned

In other words, even if *some* sites fail you'd still get `$true` returned.

Note that in general you can also suppress errors in cmdlets with `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"`, and check the return value after:

```
$result = Test-Connection -Ping "www.example.org" -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue";

if ($null -eq $result)
{
  Write-Host "No internet connection"
  Exit
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Connection available"
  # do-other things
}
```